# Fatal error with after_widget

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

I trying to create a simple widget to display a list of posts from a specific category, I'm getting an error log in `"Notice: Undefined index: after_widget in"`
I also noticed a weird thing that my widget `<aside>` class is making all the other widgets be its child, she is not closing when the widget code is done,

This is my code:

```html
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
 die('-1');
 
 
add_action( 'widgets_init', function(){
     register_widget( 'news_roller' );
}); 

function illu_news_widget(){

        wp_enqueue_style( 'your-stylesheet-name', plugins_url('/css/style.css', __FILE__), false, '1.0.0', 'all');
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', "illu_news_widget");

/**
 * Adds news_roller widget.
 */
class news_roller extends WP_Widget {

 /**
  * Register widget with WordPress.
  */
 function __construct() {
  parent::__construct(
   'news_roller', // Base ID
   __('News roller', 'isas_news'), // Name
   array( 'description' => __( 'News roller', 'isas_news' ), ) // Args
  );
 }

 /**
  * Front-end display of widget.
  *
  * @see WP_Widget::widget()
  *
  * @param array $args     Widget arguments.
  * @param array $instance Saved values from database.
  */
 public function widget( $args, $instance ) {

  extract($args);

  // Excerpt length filter
  function new_excerpt_length($length) {
     return 10;
  }
  add_filter('excerpt_length', 'new_excerpt_length');
 
      echo $args['before_widget'];

  if ( ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ) {
   echo $args['before_title'] . apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] ). $args['after_title'];
  }
        if ( ! empty( $instance['cat'] ) ) {
  ?>

       <ul class="illu_widget news-carousel">
        <?php 
         $args = array(
          'cat' => $instance["cat"]
         );
         query_posts( $args );
         while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        ?>
         <li>
          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
           <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
          </a>
         </li>
        <?php 
         endwhile;
         wp_reset_query();
        ?>
       </ul>
 <?php 
 
 }

 echo $args['after_widget'];
  
 }

 /**
  * Back-end widget form.
  *
  * @see WP_Widget::form()
  *
  * @param array $instance Previously saved values from database.
  */

 public function form( $instance ) {
  if ( isset( $instance[ 'title' ] ) ) {
   $title = $instance[ 'title' ];
  }
  else {
   $title = __( 'New title', 'isas-news' );
  }
  $cat    = $instance['cat'];
  ?>
  <p>
   <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>">
    <?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?>
   </label> 
   <input class="widefat" id="<?php 
    echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php
    echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text"
    value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>">
  </p>

  <label>
   <?php _e( 'Category' ); ?>:
   <?php wp_dropdown_categories( array(
    'name' => $this->get_field_name("cat"),
    'selected' => $instance["cat"] ) ); ?>
  </label>
      <?php
 }

 /**
  * Sanitize widget form values as they are saved.
  *
  * @see WP_Widget::update()
  *
  * @param array $new_instance Values just sent to be saved.
  * @param array $old_instance Previously saved values from database.
  *
  * @return array Updated safe values to be saved.
  */
 public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
  $instance = array();
  $instance['title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] ) : '';
        $instance['cat'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['cat'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['cat'] ) : '';
  return $instance;
 }

} // class news_roller
```

cant seem to figure it out, I'm must say my php is very limited.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Your error log tells you about an undefined index named 'after_widget'.

The code line in your error message is missing, but i think the reason of failure is in following line:

`echo $args['after_widget'];`

`$args` is an array given as parameter to the function `widget($args...`
In your `<ul>`-Part you're overwriting it with:

```
$args = array(
    'cat' => $instance["cat"]
);
```

That's why the statement `echo $args['after_widget'];` can't reference to the index 'after_widget' which is then causing the missing  Element.

Try to rename your self-made `$args` variable where you instantiate the `cat`array and you should be good to go.